# SetIndices missing in slimDx

Tags: directx, direct3d, slimdx

I am using direct3d9 of SLIMDX, however i cannot find the SetIndices() method of Device.

```
device.BeginScene();
device.SetStreamSource(0, VB, 0, 3 * sizeof(float));
device.SetIndices(IB); // This method is missing !
device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, 8, 0, 12);
device.EndScene();
```

Answer (score 0):

Oooops.

should use device.Indices = IB; instead.